# Why is my Django url redirecting to wrong url?

Tags: django

I have three django apps in a project by the name visit, main, and startup. In the a main base template I have a link on the navigation bar for redirecting user to index template in startup app. (note I have two urls by the name index but I am using namespacing).
here is my main base.html:

```
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href = '{% url 'startup:index'%}'>Startup</a>
          </li>
```

These are the site main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('visit.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('startup.urls')),

]
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">VCN</a>
          </li>
```

The urls of the startup.urls looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
app_name = 'startup'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
]
```

Instead of redirecting me to this, the link is taking me to the index of the visit app (which also has the same url name but different name space).
visit.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'visit'

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'visit/registration/login.html'}, name='login'),
   # url(r'accounts/profile/', views.profile, name='profile'), # need to change the app directory from here
    url(r'^register/', views.registration, name='registration'),
]
```

What M I doing wrong here? Is there another way to take user to another app through a link ?

Comment: Please show the main urls.py which includes those files.

Comment: I added the main website urls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple URLconfs that are included at the base path (`'^'`) and contain paths mapped to the empty path (`'^$'`). This means that the full URL for both startup.index and visit.index is the same - the empty path, `'/'`. This can't possibly work.

You need to have unique paths for each URL, which is usually done by including the URLconf under a specific prefix. For example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'^visit/', include('visit.urls')),
    url(r'^startup/', include('startup.urls')),
]
```